# Verify Google + profile/page in the web master tools

Tags: google-plus, google-search-console, google-tag-manager

How can I vefiry the google + page/profile url into web master tools?

For a example google + page url is  https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/123456789
[image]

After added this into google web master tools I have to verify that.
[image: Verification]

I need to access the google tag manager?

Please anyone give me advices to do this? Appreciate your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are not an owner of plus.google.com so you will not be able to verify it.

Comment: Oh, no.Sorry I couldn't tell.I have a domain name/web site.And I have created google + page for the web site. I have already verified the web site in the web master tools by uploading html files as in the verify method. I want to add that site's G+ page verify.Thank for the reply.